# Getting Invalid Maven home directory in IntelliJ with Maven installed via brew

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I want to set up my locally -via `brew`- installed Maven in IntelliJ (to not using the bundled one), but always getting a 'Invalid Maven home directory' prompt.

The Maven installation is here:

```
me@MBP ~ % brew list maven
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.8.4/bin/mvn
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.8.4/bin/mvnDebug
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.8.4/bin/mvnyjp
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.8.4/libexec/bin/ (4 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.8.4/libexec/boot/ (2 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.8.4/libexec/conf/ (3 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.8.4/libexec/lib/ (62 files)
```

When I try to set this path to IntelliJ, I get:

[image: Invalid Maven home directory]

What am I doing wrong?

### Edit

I've tried similar paths, but nothing seems to work:

[image: Invalid Maven home directory 2]

[image: Invalid Maven home directory 3]

Comment: Try without the `bin` directory

Comment: Have you tries set it to `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.8.4` path?

Comment: Remove the `bin` part...in your configuration...

Answer (score 14):

If you don't browse with <kbd>...</kbd> button for `Maven home path` but copy this path

Intel Mac:

```
/usr/local/opt/maven/libexec
```

Silicone Mac:

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/maven/libexec
```

into the input field then `brew update` won't break Maven access.

Answer (score 11):

Try using the libexec folder...

/opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.8.4/libexec

[image]

Comment: This should work I believe as I configured similar path in my IntelliJ in Mac and its working!!

Comment: worked great in 2022 too :)

Comment: Although your solution works, after `brew update` you have to change this setting in every project. Check my answer for lasting solution.